# convergence for symmetric, positive semi-definite operator

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Assume $u$ is a vector in the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$, $||u||=\sqrt{\langle u, u\rangle}$, where $\langle u, v\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^N u_i v_i$.
I have that $||u^{k+1}-u||\leq ||I - c A||||u^k-u||$, where $A$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite operator and $c>0$ is a parameter. Here $||(I-cA)||$ is the operator norm of $(I-cA)$.
I know that $||I - c A|| = max(|1-c \lambda_{min}|,|1-c\lambda_{max}|)$, where $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ is the least and the greatest eigenvalue of $A$, respectively. Therefore, we have
$||I - c A|| = max(1,|1-c\lambda_{max}|)$ and for $c<2/\lambda_{max}$ we get $||u^{k+1}-u||\leq||u^k-u||$.
How to get that  $||u^{k+1}-u||< ||u^k-u||$? Or in general, to show that $||u^k-u||\rightarrow 0$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$?

Comment: Can you state clearly the nature of the space you're considering,  of $u$,  and $||°||$?

Comment: How did you from $\|I-cA\|=\max\{|1-c\lambda_{\min}|,|1-c\lambda_{\max}|\}$ get $\|I-cA\|=\max\{1,|1-c\lambda_{\max}|\}$? In other words, how come that $|1-c\lambda_{min}|=1$?

Comment: Since $A$ is symmetric, positive semi-definite matrix its least eigenvalue is $0$.

Comment: Then you simply cannot prove the sharp inequality unless you assume that the error does not have components in the nullspace of $A$.

Comment: What do you mean by "error"?

Comment: $u-u_k$, obviously.